# Handle dependency collisions in a multi module project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, pdfbox

I have a project that is multi-module, and it has these module

```
Parent project directory
 -> Has its own pom which includes all modules (Parent pom)
 -> ModuleA
 -> ModuleB
 -> ModuleC (depends on commons and A,B)
 -> ModuleD (depends on commons)
 -> ModuleServer (depends on all)
 -> ModuleCommons
```

I have pdfbox as dependency whose version 2.0.x used only in ModuleD, and version 2.0.y used in Module A,B,C.

And while running the ModuleD code, parts of pdfbox dependency (fontbox) is referencing 2.0.y instead of 2.0.x, and are failing because of dependency clash (Both pdfbox and fontbox should have same version for it to properly work), some times parts of pdfbox is referencing 2.0.y pdfbox directly, how do I exclude them without causing problems.

Build is successful but while running I'm getting errors

Also the 2.0.x version of pdfbox is modified pdfbox with different groupId and artifactId, but essentially almost the same except some added/deleted clasess

Both ModuleD and Module ABC parts work fine independently (if I disable one or the other)

https://www.baeldung.com/maven-version-collision
I tried following this link and wasnt able to achieve error free collisions, also searched few other places changing many parts still without avail.

UPDATE:

Here are the poms

```
Module Commons Pom

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>repo</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>module-commons</artifactId>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.google.cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

Module A Pom

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>repo</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>module-a</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>module-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.24</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

Module B Pom

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>repo</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>module-b</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>module-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.24</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

Module C Pom

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>repo</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>module-c</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>module-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>module-a</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>module-b</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

Module D Pom

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>repo</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>module-d</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>module-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.edited.crucial</groupId> // This depends on below edited pdfbox and both are not built by us
            <artifactId>crucialjar</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.edited.crucial</groupId> // I uploaded these two Jars to nexus with different group and artifact to avoid conflicts with normal pdfbox - The Jars also have wierd names
            <artifactId>crucialpdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-ext-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.54</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.vandeseer</groupId>
            <artifactId>easytable</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

Module Server Pom

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>repo</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>module-server</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>module-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>module-a</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>module-b</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>module-c</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>module-d</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <properties>
                <project.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</project.version>
                <build.number>0</build.number>
                <build.revision>local-dev</build.revision>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>docker</id>
            // docker things and deploy things
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Maven Spring Boot -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                    <mainClass>com.company.group.module.server.ServerApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Parent Pom (Right under the repo)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>module-a</module>
        <module>module-b</module>
        <module>module-c</module>
        <module>module-commons</module>
        <module>module-server</module>
        <module>module-d</module>
    </modules>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.13</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.company.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>repo</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <name>repo</name>
    <description>asdfasdf</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</project.version>
        <feign.version>11.6</feign.version>
        <spring.google.cloud.version>3.4.2</spring.google.cloud.version>
        <spring-boot.run.jvmArguments>-Duser.timezone=IST</spring-boot.run.jvmArguments>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
    // nexus stuff
    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
    // nexus stuff
    </distributionManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.28</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign.form</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-form</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-core</artifactId>
            <version>${feign.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>${feign.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${feign.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
            <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Maven Compiler -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Maven Spring Boot -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--  Maven Deploy  -->
            <plugin>
            </plugin>

            <!--  Maven Dockerfile  -->
            <plugin>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Lombok Maven -->
            <plugin>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The error I'm getting

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationWidget.setRectangle(Ljava/util/List;)V
Error stack continues in crucialjar
Then the lines calling crucialjar in my code
```

```
The method the error references actually exists in the edited pdfbox as
public void setRectangle(List var1) {
    this.b.setItem(COSName.RECT, ((PDRectangle)var1.get(0)).getCOSArray());
}
I know this is unnecessarily done, but crucial jar uses this version for it produce its results, which I'm dependent on in ModuleD
```

This error didnt occur when I didnt implement ABC and code of D is running good in deployed envs

Comment: Why using different version? Define the version/dependency via dependencyManagement in your parent of the modules and use only the groupId/artifactId in your modules so you make sure to use only a single version instead of several....

Comment: Wrong approach - you should only use one version of pdfbox, which is 2.0.y. And actually it might be more like 2.0.z which is the current version from the pdfbox site which is (currently) 2.0.29. If you have a different behaviour in 2.0.x or 2.0.y and it seems like a bug then report it to the [pdfbox-project](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/PDFBOX/issues)

Comment: Please post your pom.xml . Usually the exclusion trick should work for the module that is dependent on the lower version.

Comment: @khmarbaise The ModuleD uses a Jar, which is an edited version of pdfbox 2.0.x, which is needed for another crucial Jar, both are from an external entity, so I need the edited 2.0.x one in ModuleD, and the actual pdfbox maven one in ABC (can be 2.0.z too np)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I'll try again with exclusion, and will post the pom if I'm not successful doing it, also where should the dependency be excluded, in the root(parent) pom or the server pom?

Comment: In the dependency that is dependent of the older version. That baeldung website really explains it well. Read the parts 3 and 4.

Comment: Are those modules stand-a-line executables like war/ear or spring boot jar's or alike? If so you can define the dependency via dependencyManagement in root pom ... and overwrite the version in module what ever... If they are related and will be combine in some way you have to make a decision and use a single version... otherwise your resulting artifactid (executable jar/war) will contain both versions and the class loading order will make the decision.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr tried excluding original pdfbox from the dep depending on older version, still getting problems while running, added the error line in quesion

Comment: setRectangle is a method of PDAnnotation, but definitively not as a list. The current version is 2.0.29 not 2.0.24. I wonder if some of your dependencies expect an extremely old version.

Comment: You are using both 2.0.8 and 2.0.24 versions but not sure which one crucialpdfbox.jar is bringing up. Could you double check how many pdfbox jars are included in the final jar (suppose you have an executable jar). As suggested, keeping all versions is not the correct approach, so, as looking on Module D and align the packaged version (2.0.8 vs 2.0.24) is not supported, you can only downgrade the part on your code, which can be rebuilt/repackaged.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Yes its present in the edited version of pdfbox, I added the method it references in the edited pdfbox above, so crucial jar is referencing actual pdfbox instead of the edited one, how do I make it not do it

Comment: The method that fails doesn't exist. Find out what version "crucialjar" requests. I doubt it is 2.0.* . Re 2.0.8 vs 2.0.24, replace both with 2.0.29. However this won't solve the problem about the outdated call.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr that method was in "crucialpdfbox" jar, shared by the same people, it has the method but with a different signature, currently I solved this problem by separating out the ModuleD into a separate micro service, but wanted to see if I could have the ones using real pdfbox and the one using modified one inside same repo/microservice

Comment: You could try "shading" of conflicting versions if you absolutely need both. Sadly this is something I know nothing about.